# Writing a weekly recurring time interval (ISO 8601)

Tags: time, iso8601

i need a correct weekly ISO 8601 [recurring time interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Repeating_intervals).

For example, repeat:

Each Monday, 19:00.

I already tried a lot of examples, but nothing worked correctly :-(

Thx for any help!

Comment: Take look at this https://github.com/cylc/cylc/wiki/ISO-8601

Comment: @user3160044 What exactly is your question? Do you have a question about programming? You have not mentioned any programming language or library. You have not stated exactly the problem.

Answer (score 7):

R/2014-W01-1T19:00:00/P1W

Represents a unbounded recurrence with a start date and a duration of one week. The recurrence starts at the first day (Monday) of the week number 01 in the week year 2014. I have used a [week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), but you can substitute it with a [calendar date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) or [ordinal date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates), just make sure the date falls on a Monday.

Comment: As far as I understand, your example has a duration of one week. I think events usually have a shorter duration, like one hour. Can you express a duration of one hour with a one week recurrence?

Comment: See also this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229717/iso-8601-define-repeating-interval-on-thanksgiving

Comment: @MihaiCapotă A week duration cannot combined with a time component (ISO 8601 4.4.3 Duration), but you can combine a day component with a hour component:  `P7DT1H`. If you have any further questions, please open a new question, comments is not the place to ask questions.

Comment: I meant to request a clarification, not to ask a new question. I can't speak for @Phil, the question author, but as I said in my first comment, I think it useful to also specify the duration of the event, not only the recurrence. Thank you for answering the question I linked.