# How do I express coming Monday in iso8601?

Tags: iso8601

While answering [Regexp matching ISO8601 date/time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357870/regexp-matching-iso8601-date-time-format) I wondered how you express *first coming Monday* or *repeat every monday* in ISO8601.

My guess would be something like:

```
W-1
R/W-1
```

But I cannot find a confirmation of that.

Comment: You don't. ISO8601 defines timestamps or intervals (durations). If you want to specify thinks like "next monday", you would have to use your own syntax, though that may be based on ISO8601.

Answer (score 0):

ISO 8601 has the concept of [week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) which allow you to specify a week of the year and the day of the year.  In the following example `2014-W01-1` means the first week of 2014 on Monday.  Then repeat that every week using `P1W`

```
R/2014-W01-1T00:00:00/P1W
```

[Seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928142/4789989)