# ISO 8601 Define repeating interval on Thanksgiving?

Tags: date, datetime, iso8601, dateinterval, datetimeformatinfo

I'm trying to define an interval that repeats every year, starting on the 4th Thursday of November at 13:30z and ending on the same day at 15:00z. Can this be done using ISO 8601?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of recurrence can't be expressed with current ISO 8601. Next version of ISO 8601 will most likely include a recurring time interval format based on iCalendar (RFC 5545:2009).